# Raise Error instead of redirect and flash errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When I fill form validation wrong - it raises an error(screen included below) instead of redirect to *new_product_path* and flash all the errors. If I use form correctly with all validations passed it works fine, and redirect me to *index*. Also Product belongs_to :user and User has_many :products.

```
%h1 Products
=form_with scope: :product, url: products_path, local: true do |p|
  -if @product.errors.any?
    =pluralize(@product.error.count, 'error')
    prohibited this product from being saved: 
    %ul
      =@product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li
          =msg
  %div
    =p.label :product_name
    %br
    =p.text_field :product_name
  %div
    =p.label :description
    %br
    =p.text_field :description
  %div
    =p.submit 'Create'
```

controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
        @product = Product.create(product_params)

        if @product.save!
            flash[:notice] = "New product create"
            redirect_to products_index_path
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "Something Gone wrong"
            render new_product_path
        end
  end

  def update
  end

  def delete
  end

    private
    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:product_name, :description)
    end
end
```

model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    validates :product_name, uniqueness: true,
                    format: { with: /[A-Z]{3}[-][1-9]{3}/ }

    validates :description, presence: true,
                       length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `@product.save!`. I had to use `save` instead of `save!`.

```
def create
  @product = Product.create(product_params)

  if @product.save     # <-- Here
    flash[:notice] = "New product create"
    redirect_to products_index_path
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Something Gone wrong"
    render new_product_path
  end
end
```